# Opening 4 Terminal windows, resizing them und connect via ssh to server using a script on OS X

Tags: automation, macos

I would like to do the following thing:

Click on a script or executable and automatically open 4 Terminal Windows. Each Terminal window should open a command like: "ssh server.com tail -f /var/log/log.txt".
The command for each window will be different.
All 4 windows should be tiled on the desktop, so I can watch them simultaniously.

I tried to do it with automator or a Terminal script, however I didn't find a good solution.

How would you do something like that? Which tool would you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use AppleScript. This'll get you started:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    repeat 4 times
        do script "ssh server.com tail -f /var/log/log.txt"
    end repeat
    repeat with win in windows 1 thru 4
        set bounds of win to {0, 0 1000, 1000}
    end repeat
end tell
```

(You'll have to play with the window moving part, but that's the basic idea of how you do it.)

Comment: thanks. worked perfectly for me. Now I can have my mac sitting around showing me the server's log files while I have to work on the other machine. great :)

Answer (score 0):

Create settings in Preferences for each window you want.  You can set the command in the Shell tab.  Then open each of the settings in turn with Shell > New Window > [settings name], resize/move them as you like, and use Window > Save Windows as Group... to give the group a name.

Then you can open all four windows with Window > Open Window Group > [group name].

Comment: Wish I could accept your answer too. Seems to be an easy way to achive something actually not so easy. However, I personally prefer the approach using AppleScript as I don't need to create special settings and can have an icon lying on my desktop that does all the work.

Comment: Not a problem, if the other answer works better for you, feel free!  To mark an answer as helpful but not accepted, you can upvote it instead (click the ▲ icon).  You probably want to both upvote *and* accept jtbandes's answer.

Comment: (Sorry, didn't realize users with low reputation can't even upvote! I voted up your question, so hopefully you'll get enough rep to do that soon.)